# Another database table or a json object

Tags: database, json

I have two tables: stores and users. Every user is assigned to a store. I thought "What if I could just save all the users assigned to a store as a json object and save that json object in a field of a store." So in other words, user's data will be stored in a field instead of it's own table. There will be around 10 people to a store. I would like to know which method will require the least amount of processing for the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most databases are relational, meaning there's no reason to be putting multiple different fields in one column.  Besides being more work for you having to put them together and take them apart, you'd be basically ignoring the strength of the database.

If you were ever to try to access the data from another app, you'd have to make yourself go through additional steps.  It also limits sorting and greatly adds to your querying difficulties  (i.e. can't say where field = value because one field contains many values)

In your specific example, if the users at a store change, rather than being able to do a very efficient delete from the users table (or modify which store they're assigned to) you'd have to fetch the data and edit it, which would double your overhead.

Joins exist for a reason, and they are efficient.  So, don't fear them!